# Show partner address into tree view - OpenERP

Tags: python, xml, tree, odoo

In `res.partner` form view of `sale.order`, you got this code:

```
<field name="partner_id" on_change="onchange_partner_id(partner_id, context)" domain="[('customer','=',True)]" context="{'search_default_customer':1, 'show_address': 1}" options='{"always_reload": True}'/>
```

This view takes `res.partner` address into form ie: `context="{'search_default_customer':1, 'show_address': 1}"` now, I want this same behavior BUT on tree view.

I just copied this `context` into tree view, on `partner_id` field, but nothing happens, I tried many ways, with no results.

I'd like to have the partner's address on tree view also.

Anybody knows how to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my point of view, `context` is used for often available as contextual actions on resources;

context is  nothing but a python directory.

In your case this context will be update with your predefined value like here you have update it with 2 keys.

so when you use any method on this field like on_change so in that case you can use this updated context.

Comment: Thank you, I see... Well I don't know how can I take the partner_id address into that view...

Comment: as a suggestion, create a new field eg. `street,city,zip,country` and make a `on_change.` In `on_change,` you will get `partner_id.` just return that `partner_id` address.

Comment: Seems legit, I think If I do this also with product.product name, let's say a field called 'servicios', with an onchange directed to product object should do the same trick, I'm testing it right now :)